# C 2D char array ("Warning initialization from incompatible pointer")

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, declaration

I would like to create a 2D string array so i try that:

```
char **value[] = {"integer", "char", "string", "octal", "hexa_min", "hexa_maj", "pointer", "integer", "bin_int", "non_printable", "unsigned_int", NULL};
```

but i have a warning for each str of my array.

https://pastebin.com/bwJtB1CR

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: You need one level less of indirection: `char *value[] = {"integer", ...`

Comment: That's not really a "2d array", it's an array of pointers. Where each pointer is a pointer to the first character of a (read-only!) string literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters this record

```
char **value[] = /*...*/;
```

does not mean a declaration of a 2D-array. It is a declaration of one-dimensional array elements of which has the type `char **`.

Moreover the type of elements of the array and the type of initializers in this declaration

```
char **value[] = {"integer", "char", "string", "octal", "hexa_min", "hexa_maj", "pointer", "integer", "bin_int", "non_printable", "unsigned_int", NULL};
```

are incompatible.

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

String literals in C have types of character arrays. For example the string literal `"integer"` has the type `char[8]`. As the quote says the string literal used as an initializer is implicitly converted to pointer of the type `char *` that points to the first character of the string literal.

So in the declaration there are used initializers of the type `char *` while the declared object has the type `char **`.

It would be correctly to write

```
char *value[] = {"integer", "char", "string", "octal", "hexa_min", "hexa_maj", "pointer", "integer", "bin_int", "non_printable", "unsigned_int", NULL};
```

But as it was already mentioned it is a declaration of a one-dimensional array of pointers of the type `char *`.  For most tasks that deals with strings such a declaration is suitable.

If you want indeed to declare a two dimensional array then you should calculated the maximum size of the string literals including the terminating zero. Rge maximum string literal used as an initializer is `"non_printable"` it has the type `char[14]`.
Thus the two-dimensional character array should be declared the following way. Take into account that the initializer `NULL` shall be removed.

```
char value[][14] = {"integer", "char", "string", "octal", "hexa_min", "hexa_maj", "pointer", "integer", "bin_int", "non_printable", "unsigned_int" };
```

But it seems what you need is the one-dimensional array pf pointers shown above. The correct decision depends on whether you are going to change the elements of the array and in this case you have to use the two-dimensional array or you are not going to change the elements of the array and in this case you should use the one-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

```
char value[12][30] = {
"integer",
 "char", 
"string", 
"octal", 
"hexa_min", 
"hexa_maj",
 "pointer", 
"integer", 
"bin_int", 
"non_printable", 
"unsigned_int", 
"NULL"};
```

Always remember when you declare 2D array as follows: 
array2D[No_Of_Rows][No_Of_Coloums];

Comment: Suppose in value[0] I need to store 50 characters, will your suggestion works ? why don't you use  char *value[12],  using this declaration you can store any no characters in value[0].

Comment: Yes, this is a true 2D array, but it seems that OP wants an array of pointers to `char`: `NULL` and `"NULL"` are not the same.

Comment: -achal I couldn't get. Would you please elaborate ? That seemed interesting, I don't know that concept.

Comment: -Keine Lust  you are right but he/she didn't mention clearly whether he/she wants a array of pointers or 2D array of string

Comment: We are not obliged to answer wrong or ambiguous questions :) this fits better as a comment.